# Hide DrawerLayout system bars but layouts remain

Tags: android, kotlin, system

I can't figure out why the system bars still remain in landscape although I have used

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, nView).let { controller ->
    controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
}
```

But it seems it just hides the 'icons
[image]

[image]

Any idea is appreciated

**Later Edit:
Made a test and realized is from the activity layout androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window,false) to false. This is working fine for my app.

```
 private fun hideSystemUi() {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, binding.videoView).let { controller ->
            controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm, does your app has a DrawerLayout as main layout in Activity ?

Comment: If I replace DrawerLayout with Constraint, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Was set android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

after I deleted this line, the fullscreen without system bars was working fine